# symlinks doesnt working on ubuntu localhost

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, symlink

I have problem. Im using ubuntu. I take symblink to my /var/www/

ln -sf /home/user/project/www/project_name

But as i try to load  it in localhost it returns me error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /project_name on this server.

---

as i copy folder directly to /var/www/ it works fine.

What is reason that it isnt working with symlinks?

Thank you

Jan

Comment: Is this a question about a particular HTTPD server?  You don't mention anything about that.   Are you just trying to access things in bash?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

you must set executable to folder "project_name" on which you have symlink.